# How to force the column names to be evenly distributed if I need to align by decimal point?

Tags: tables

I am a new learner with table, and I had this strange problem with my huge table. Here is the partial code which can replicate the issue:

```
\documentclass[floatsintext,man,12pt,a4paper]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{setspace} %not needed double spacing by default....
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,booktabs}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for decimal alignment
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{document}
\title{xx}

\shorttitle{Pxx}

\author{dd}
\affiliation{xx}

\leftheader{xxx}

\abstract{}

\keywords{xxx}


\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
\small
\caption{xxx}
\centering
\tabcolsep=0.11cm
\scalebox{0.9}{
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-align-text-post=false]@{}*{14}{S[add-integer-zero = false]@{}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{1em}}l}{Items} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ difference \textit{t}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14}\\
\midrule
    8. Love & -6.84*** & -.20*  & .09  & .10   & .02  & .06  & .08  & .05  & .05  & .00    & .13  & .04  & .03  & .14  & -.11 \\
    9. Hate & 5.87* & .05  & .15  & .08  & .19*  & .26**  & .06  & .15  & .17  & .06  & .19*  & .08  & .27** & .14  & -.24** \\
\midrule\\[-2.5ex]
\multicolumn{14}{l}{\textit{Note.}*\textit{p}$<$.05, **\textit{p}$<$.01, ***\textit{p}$<$.001}  \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: this is the screen shot of the table output.]

I don't understand why the space between 4 and 5 (the 6th and 7th col) is much larger than others.

UPDATE: I solved the space between *** and negative number by adding [table-align-text-post=false], however I still cannot resolve the issue of the space between the 6th and 7th col...

Comment: What is `\end{document}][1]` supposed to do?

Comment: I was trying to insert a picture there and it became merge together when I submit the post, I have just edited it...

Comment: and it added many \ automatically... should I delete them otherwise the code won't run....

Comment: Yes, it would be much better to delete them.

Comment: removed manually now, don't know why they appeared automatically...

Comment: Compilation stops here with this error message: `./tab-1.tex:36: Undefined control sequence. <argument> \@shorttitle l.36 \end{document}`. Maybe you should also try to make this example shorter.

Comment: I resolved the space between * and negative number just now by adding "table-align-text-post=false", but the spacing between 6th and 7th col is still too wide....

Comment: @fpast, i have modified the code -- apa6 needs the shorttitle entry so i added all the fields required by apa6 in the code now should works. thanks!

Comment: @ceoec: You should really consider using `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` to replicate `<col spec>` a total of `<num>` times, rather than writing it out manually.

Comment: @Werner, thanks so much for your suggestion! I don't know I can do this and it was very difficult to count manually .... i edit the above source code too.

Answer (score 2):

Column 5 was wide because the `**` is balanced by white space as you are centering on the `.` Also the layout was a bit strained as you were removing all the inter-column space from the headings but had inter-column space for the data.

Scaling tables is evil and as it seemed to fit without, I removed that as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[floatsintext,man,12pt,a4paper]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{setspace} %not needed double spacing by default....
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,booktabs}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for decimal alignment
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{document}
\title{xx}

\shorttitle{Pxx}

\author{dd}
\affiliation{xx}

\leftheader{xxx}

\abstract{}

\keywords{xxx}


\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
\small
\caption{xxx}
\centering
\tabcolsep=0.11cm
\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-align-text-post=false]*{14}{S[add-integer-zero = false]}@{}}
\toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{@{}{c}}{Items} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{difference $t$} &  
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{7} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{9} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{12} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{13} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{14}\\
\midrule
    8. Love & -6.84\rlap{***} & -.20\rlap{*}  & .09  & .10   & .02  & .06  & .08  & .05  & .05  & .00    & .13  & .04  & .03  & .14  & -.11 \\
    9. Hate & 5.87\rlap{*} & .05  & .15  & .08  & .19*  & .26\rlap{**}  & .06  & .15  & .17  & .06  & .19\rlap{*}  & .08  & .27\rlap{**} & .14  & -.24** \\
\midrule\\[-2.5ex]
\multicolumn{14}{l}{\textit{Note.}*\textit{p}$<$.05, **\textit{p}$<$.01, ***\textit{p}$<$.001}  \\
\end{tabular}%

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is it possible to make 1 2 3 4... evenly distributed?